# Coloured subsection AND text right after the subsection name

Tags: color, titlesec, code, subsection, sectsty

I'm facing a problem due to the incompatibility between the packages TITLESEC and SECTSTY.

What I want is to have a coloured subsection name, which I provided with

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\subsectionfont{\color{E}}
```

Where E is the colour I defined with RGB and so on.

The incompatible part is this one

```
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}[runin]
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
```

Which should able the possibility of writing text right after the subsection name.

Is there a solution I can use? (I spoke of subsection, but the same holds for sections).

Thank you

Comment: (1) Please always provide a full minimal exmaple that others can copy and test as is. (2) You should not be using these two packages at the same time as they both mess with the same code which leads to problems. (3), yuo should exaplain exactly what you mean by `The incompatible part is this one`

Comment: If I understand the abvove correctly, you use the `sectsty` package only for coloring the font. Why don't you just say `\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\normalfont\large\bfseries\color{E}}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}`? You would not need the  `sectsty` package then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you want to achieve eventually, as you did not provide much information. But if you only use the `sectsty` package for adding color to the subsection title, you should know that you can totally do this with just the `titlesec` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\definecolor{E}{named}{red}

\titleformat{\section}[runin]
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]
{\normalfont\large\bfseries\color{E}}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Section} 
\lipsum[1]

\subsection{Section} 
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]